# GA Enhanced Ecommerce max product restriction?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol, enhanced-ecommerce

I've been tasked with updating our ecomm tracking but have been told it was not previously implemented with Enhanced Ecommerce because:

> ... it has limits around number of products. As we have 100,000's of 'Products' due to ... it's not a good fit.

Nonetheless, I am unable to find and conclusive evidence via any (non or official) sources of such limitation/s.

I'd like to upgrade to Enhanced Ecommerce for obvious reasons so does anyone have an idea of limitations around unique product (by id/sku) maximums or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no limit for collecting unique SKUs or other dimensions, but you might have problems during reporting. Limits apply during the processing of high cardinality dimensions, and you might get many of them aggregated as `(other)` values among your dimensions.

> Each report dimension (e.g., Page, Browser, Screen Resolution, etc.)
>   has a number of values that can be assigned to it. The total number of
>   unique values for a dimension is known as its cardinality. For
>   instance, the Mobile (or ga:isMobile) dimension has two potential
>   values (Yes or No), so the cardinality for that dimension is two.
>   Other dimensions can have any number of values assigned. For example,
>   the Page dimension has a different value for every URL that appears on
>   your site.
>
> Dimensions with a large number of possible values are known as
>   high-cardinality dimensions. Reports containing high-cardinality
>   dimensions may be affected by Analytics system limits, resulting in
>   the creation of a rolled-up (other) entry in the report to contain the
>   data that exceeds these limits.

For further details and actual limits you can check this [support article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009671?hl=en).

Even if these limitations get applied on SKU level, you can benefit from Product Category level reports, and general shopping/checkout behavior reports.

Comment: Thanks @kgrg that's really good to know! That would be the same case for standard Ecommerce tracking though too wouldn't it?

Comment: I haven't seen a standard ecommerce property with such scenario. Although, based on the article, I assume, that all high cardinality dimensions behave this way, including standard ecommerce product sku.